# How does light heat things up?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light

If heat is due to vibration of a material how does light heat the material up?

I placed my phone under the sun (I forgot it was there) and when I picked it up after an hour, I noticed it was extremely hot. So it got me thinking, if light is made of photons and photons are massless. How does a massless particle which collides with the material heat it up? Without mass there would be no force (Newton's second law) which should mean there wouldn't be any vibrations, which means no heat.

I know it's wrong but I'm not sure where I'm wrong. So to reiterate my question: how does light heat up material?

Comment: Similar question here:   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/254005/does-visible-light-heat-things-up     Light isn't massless either.  It has zero rest mass but it has mass equivalent to it's energy.   Here's a solid explanation to what precisely happens:  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-exactly-does-light-tr/

Answer (score 2):

We use microwaves: we eat a hot food and become happy. The microwave uses the lights, but their wave length is about micrometers. So we cannot see them.

The light is electro-magnetic field, which can accelerate (charged) particles. So clearly we can heat up materials with light.

Of course, the rest mass of light is zero. However, light has it's energy.