# Heating due to sun's radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

It is commonly said that heat received from sun is due to the infrared part of solar radiation. But from Wikipedia i found that most of the energy is received from visible light. Then why do we say that infrared is responsible for heating of earth?
[Solar radiation (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg)

Comment: We don't. Can you quote an example?

Comment: I recently had a question in my exam asking which light from sun is responsible for heating of earth, and  when i checked the answer key it said infrared was the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does visible light heat things up?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254005/)

Comment: Submitted as duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254005/

Answer (score 3):

One has to integrate the spectrum to answer this question:

[image: sunrad]

> [In terms of energy,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Measurement) sunlight at Earth's surface is around 52 to 55 percent infrared (above 700 nm), 42 to 43 percent visible (400 to 700 nm), and 3 to 5 percent ultraviolet (below 400 nm)

As this is a wikipedia quote you must be mistaken. Maybe because you saw the peak in the visible you forgot that one has to integrate?